# What exactly is virtualenv.py?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I know of `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` and `.py` stands for `python`.
When I run `virtualenv` in `PyCharm IDE` this comes up:

```
Usage: virtualenv.py
```

I just recently came across this and tried search for it but I couldn't find it. What exactly is `virtualenv.py` and is there any difference to it compared to just to `virtualenv` and `virtualwrapper`? I don't have `pip3` installed for both the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `virtualenv.py` is the actual program written in python. If you install it via pip or pip3, it automatically installs it as `virtualenv` and we can use it. However, here it seems that `virtualenv` is just calling the `virtualenv.py` and hence you are getting that in the usage section.

[Here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv.py) is the source code of the `virtualenv.py`

Comment: The code is really long.